# Trying to avoid Traffic on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am using C# ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor

I have a Grid in ASP.NET MVC Razor View that displays the user records. Is there any way to show the new users in Grid without sending the async request to server after each 1 min ?

I searched on Google a lot. Now, finally I am posting the query here to get any clue for this solution to avoid Traffic on Server. As this page will be visible to at least 20,000 users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Christos approach is the right one!, Just to add more info about it for an ASP.NET solution I would it use SignalR, that lets you implement a simple server/client communication and it's cross browser (it has several polyfills that if it cannot use web sockets it will use server-sent event, and so on), and the best part is that you don't need to worry about that implementation.

Once your clients are connected to the signalR server you can notify them  everytime you need to add a new item to the grid.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of the the publish/subscriber pattern. This can be done using for instance a redis server.

> In software architecture, publish–subscribe is a messaging pattern
>   where senders of messages, called publishers, do not program the
>   messages to be sent directly to specific receivers, called
>   subscribers. Instead, published messages are characterized into
>   classes, without knowledge of what, if any, subscribers there may be.
>   Similarly, subscribers express interest in one or more classes, and
>   only receive messages that are of interest, without knowledge of what,
>   if any, publishers there are.

Please have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).

Doing so, the first time a client requests data from the server will subscribe to the server for taking any updates. Once any update arrives, the server will push the update to the clients that have subscribed, without requiring from the client to make any other request to the server.

As for implementation details, please have a look [here](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub).

Comment: How would you implement the publish/subscribe pattern between individual web browsers and the web server?

Comment: Isn't correct as an idea? I am aware of this pattern but I had never the chance to implement it and I thought that should have been suitable for this case. If itsn't please let me know to remove the post.

Comment: I think the idea is fine, but I don't have experience implementing it practically in a browser.  I supposed Web Sockets could provide a good basis for this but have not worked with them personally.  Found this googling: http://faye.jcoglan.com/node/websockets.html  Perhaps explore implementation options and update your answer to be more specific to the OP's situation.